# Need help with some Calculus II power series problems?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am trying to find the interval of convergence for two power series right now.

They are:

A. $\frac{1+2n}{1+3n}x^n$ where $n$ starts at $0$ and approaches infinity

B. $\frac{1+2^n}{1+3^n}x^n$ where $n$ starts at $0$ and approaches infinity

Thanks in advance for your help with these problems!

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

For the first by ratio test

$$\left|\frac{(1+2(n+1))(x^{n+1})}{ (1+3(n+1))}\frac{ (1+3n)}{(1+2n)(x^n)}\right|=|x|\frac{(2n+3)(3n+1)}{(3n+4)(2n+1)}$$

For the second by ratio test

$$\left|\frac{(1+2^{n+1})(x^{n+1})}{ (1+3^{n+1})}\frac{ (1+3^n)}{(1+2^n)(x^n)}\right|=|x|\frac{(2\cdot2^n+1)(3^n+1)}{(3\cdot3^n+1)(2^n+1)}$$

From these in both cases we can find the condition of convercence for $|x|<R$ then we need to check for the cases $|x|=R$.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful information. It appears from your computations that as n approaches infinity, problem one will converge to |x|(2/3)(3/2) and will end up with an interval of (-1, 1). It also appears that the second problem will converge to |x|(2/3) and end up with an interval of |2x/3| < 1 or (-3/2, 3/2). Am I figuring correctly? Thanks!

Comment: @StephenLanford Yes it is and what about |x|=1?

Comment: My apologies, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @StephenLanford usually by these criteria we can find the value for convergence $|x|<R$ (un less $R=\infty$) then we need always to check also the cases $|x|=R$ when $R\neq \infty$ since these test are not conclusive.

Comment: Are you saying I need to plug in my values of -1, 1 and -3/2, 3/2 into my original functions and see whether they converge or diverge?

Comment: @StephenLanford Yes indeed in some cases we can find that we have convegence also for $x=\pm R$. We need alway to check these cases to complete.

Comment: I will show my computations for the two problems separately:

Comment: @StephenLanford That's good!

Comment: Problem One. When x = -1, we have (1+2n)(-1)^n / 1+3n, which diverges since the limit is fluctuating back and forth; it does not exist. When x=1, we have (1+2n)(1)^n / 1+3n, which equals 2/3. Because neither of these functions converges to zero, neither of them can be put in brackets. So the final interval of convergence answer is (-1, 1). Am I correct on this first problem?

Comment: @StephenLanford Yes exactly!

Comment: Problem Two. When x = -3/2, we have (1+2^n)(-3/2)^n / 1+3^n, which diverges since the limit is fluctuating back and forth---because of the (-1)^n; it also does not exist. When x=3/2, we have a (simplified) answer of just 3^n / 3^n which diverges to 1 when n approaches infinity. Again, neither of these functions converges to zero, so again neither of them can be put in brackets. So the final interval of convergence answer is (-3/2, 3/2). Is this correct, or did I miss something on this problem?

Comment: @StephenLanford It's ok, you are done! In this case. Remember to check always the bounds. Bye

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! You are a genius and very helpful. Is there a way I can help to give you some extra points?

Comment: @StephenLanford You are welcome! I hope we'll meet agan for some other OP! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Cauchy-Hadamard formula and

$$\begin{align*}&\sqrt[n]{\frac{1+2n}{1+3n}}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{1+2n}}{\sqrt[n]{1+3n}}\\{}\\
&\sqrt[n]{\frac{1+2^n}{1+3^n}}=\frac23\sqrt[n]{\frac{1+\frac1{2^n}}{1+\frac1{3^n}}}\end{align*}$$